# is that possible to calculate difference between two values in the same array php?

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know if that possible or not. I have an array('2','4','9','16'), I want to  get the value of (2-4), and (4-9), and (9-16). Each one minus the next number, do you have any way to achieve that? thanks.

Comment: of course it is, tried anything?

Comment: It sounds pretty doable by looping through each value and subtracting the array's next value. How do you want the output? Another array with the results?

Comment: I had tried 'for $X loop', but this is not the best method for me base on my code.

Comment: http://php.net/for or http://php.net/foreach.

Comment: @ Eduardo López, it doesn't matter how the result output, but array with results prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array=array('2','4','9','16');

foreach( $array as $k=> $v){
 if($v !=end($array)){
   echo $v-$array[$k+1]."\n";
 }
}
```

updated to exclude 16-0

Comment: I have tried but it's giving me `Unsupported operand types`

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is. E.g. like this:

```
$array = array(2, 4, 9, 16);

$output = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $number) {
    if (isset($array[$key+1])) {
        $output[$number] = $number - $array[$key+1];
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

The `$output` array looks like this then:

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  int(-2)
  [4]=>
  int(-5)
  [9]=>
  int(-7)
}
```

Note that there is no entry for the last number, as you can, naturally, not substract the next number of that one from it, as there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Another method for the record:

```
$test_array = array(1,5,12,24,79);
$new_array = array();

$array_length = sizeof($test_array);

for($n = 1; $n <= ($array_length - 1); $n++)
{
    // Get the current value
    $x = current($test_array);

    // Move the internal pointer
    next($test_array);

    // Get the next value
    $y = current($test_array);

    // Calculate the result in the new array
    $new_array[] = $x-$y;
}
```

Comment: what if I want to do like `5-1, 12-5,24-12,79-24`?

Comment: You reverse `$new_array[] = $y-$x;`